# Testing localhost on iPhone - no sound

Tags: iphone, localhost

I'm testing an application locally on my iPhone, I can access it through 192.168.15.101:5500. But for some reason the sound is not working. I've tested on my huawei tablet and it works well. Is there some configuration I'd need to do for it to work on iOS?

Thank you for your help.